# NLog Block overflow action

Tags: nlog

this is the sentence in NLog's documentation:
"Block - The application-thread will block until the background-writer-thread has taken the next batch. Avoids loosing important logevents, but can block all application-threads."

who will determine which logevents are important? if it's based on level of log, which log levels are important??

Comment: Happy that you found the wiki-page https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target - `overflowAction="Block"` means that it will never discard any logevents. So you will not loose logevents independent of it being important or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

In the wiki-page it is written that it avoids loosing **"important"** logevents, and this made me to mistake. So all the logevents are preserved regardless of log level?

Comment: Yes all logevents are preserved independent of log-level (including the important ones), when using `overflowAction="Block"`